# How can I customise ionic global css colors succesfully?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to change the ion-item background to a white background with opacity to make the text more legible, however when I test out changing the colors in the variables css, i am unsuccessful.

this is the outcome when I change the color = "primary" in the html
[image]

However when I customise the color with the following code, I get no change in the view.

global CSS

```
  --ion-color-test: #1d8f9e;
```

HTML

```
 <ion-item color="test" class="item item-trns text-center">
        <ion-label style="color:black!important"position="floating" >Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

I get this result

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide your css code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow this guide here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors#adding-colors

In short:

Create your color inside "root" selector:

```
:root {

  // other base colors above:

  // you new color below:

  --ion-color-favorite: #69bb7b;
  --ion-color-favorite-rgb: 105,187,123;
  --ion-color-favorite-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-favorite-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-favorite-shade: #5ca56c;
  --ion-color-favorite-tint: #78c288;
}
```

Then add the class inside the variables.scss and its very important to keep the naming of the class here:

```
.ion-color-favorite {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-favorite);
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-favorite-rgb);
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-favorite-contrast);
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-favorite-contrast-rgb);
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-favorite-shade);
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-favorite-tint);
}
```

> The class must be written in the format .ion-color-{COLOR} where
>   {COLOR} is the name of the color to add

Now you can do color="favorite" in your template code.

To make it all easier Ionic team did this color creation tool:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors#new-color-creator